# Lucene 4.1 : How search text with HunspellStemmer and get suggestions?

Tags: lucene, lexical-analysis, hunspell

I want to parse text files with lucene using HunspellStemmer to check for spelling errors.  I will use Hunspell dictionaries that's why I want to use HunspellStemmer.

At this point I'm not sure how I should parse the files and do the checking.

Could I use a Standard Analyser with WordFilter to index the text in a file and check Term by term if the keyword is present in HunspellDictionary.

I did that and it works, not sure it's the optimal solution, but if I want to output 3-5 suggestions by word not present, I have no idea what do to.

I could use a IndexerSearch  when I use a PlainTextDictionnary, but no idea how to get that functionality with HunspellDictionary.  (it doesn't implement Dictionary).

any help will be really appreciate.

thanks

examples that I want to check :    hell, hello, hall, helli.  I'm hoping to have suggestions for "helli" using a Hunspell.